# VueJS v-bind property not updated immediately after AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vue.js, axios

I have a table where each row corresponds to an event. Each event has a set of timeslots rendered as span elements and each timeslot is assigned the **na** class (with v-bind) only when its **stopsales** property is true

The timeslots are fetched asynchronously from an ajax request (*loadData*).

I call **loadData** to render my timeslots initially. There are also 2 buttons I use to call the function below to change the stopsales property of some of them:

```
<div v-for="event in events">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" @change="handleEvents(event); " :id="event" 
           :value="event" v-model="selectedEvents">
      {{event.name}}
  </label>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="toggle(true);">Activate</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="toggle(false);">Stop</button>

<td v-for="event in selectedEvents">
  <span v-for="(ev, index, key)  in event.timeslot">
    <span class="label label-default" v-bind:class="{ na: ev.stopsales }"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" :timeslot="ev.timeslotId" 
           v-on:click="addToToggleCheck($event,ev.timeslotId)">
  </span>
</td>


<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      events: [
        { 
          id: 1, 
          name: "Event 1",                  
        },
        { 
          id: 2, 
          name: "Event 2",                  
        }
      ],
      selectedEvents: [],
      toggleCheck: []
    },
    methods: {
      loadData(event) {
        axios.post(url, {
          event: event.id
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          var response_item = response.data.data[0];
          event.timeslot = response_item.timeslot;
        });
      },
      handleEvents(event) {
        var currentObj = this;
        this.selectedEvents.forEach(function (selectedEvent) {
          if (selectedEvent.id === event.id) {
            currentObj.loadData(event);
          }
        });
      },
      addToToggleCheck(event, timeslotId) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          this.toggleCheck[timeslotId] = true;
        } else {
           this.toggleCheck[timeslotId] = false;
        }
      },
      toggle(activate){
        var selectedToToggle = [];
        var _this = this;
        for (var key in this.toggleCheck) {
          if (this.toggleCheck[key]) {
            selectedToToggle.push(key);
          }
        }
        axios.post(toggleUrl, {
          evIds: selectedToToggle,
          activate: activate
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          _this.selectedEvents.forEach(function (selectedEvent) {
          _this.loadData(selectedEvent);
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now here comes the weird part. If **selectedEvents** only  *contains 1 event*,
when I call the **toggle** function, the **na** class is immediately applied as normal to the span elements.

However, if **selectedEvents** *contains 2 events*, when I call the **toggle** function, the **na** class is immediately applied only to the span elements whose parent is the last event chosen. The **na** class is not yet assigned to the span elements that are children of the first event.**However** if I do anything else in my table that does not even involve those 2 functions, like for example opening a modal, the **na** class is applied to those elements too.

Is this some VueJS timing issue where the DOM is only updated after a JS event is triggered? Is there a queue of changes waiting to be deployed on the next event trigger?

Comment: No, Vue doesn't wait for any JS events. Seems more like a reactivity issue on your side. How exactly your `data()` function looks like?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with `data() ` function. `loadData()` is responsible for fetching the data from my backend. If you mean the backend function, how is it important? The data fetched is correct based on `console.log()`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: Ah I see. I updated my  question with much more code and a more specific description of the problem. Please check it out.

Comment: @ThatGuy your data also looks wrong - it should be returning an object and setup like this: `data() { return { events: [ { id: 1, name: 'event'}]}}`

Comment: @maxshuty That's true for components but not entirely needed for a root instance. Although I agree it is a good habbit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addToToggleCheck` seems problematic. Setting array value using indexer is not reactive (Vue cannot detect the change - applies to Vue 2.x).

Replace `this.toggleCheck[timeslotId] = true/false;` with `Vue.set(this.toggleCheck, timeslotId, true/false);`

Read about [Change Detection Caveats for Arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

And if your code really looks exactly as in your question, similar problem is in the `loadData` method on `event.timeslot = response_item.timeslot;` line where you are adding new property to an event object

Read about [Change Detection Caveats for Objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Either use `Vue.set(event, 'timeslot', response_item.timeslot)` or introduce the property in data:

```js
data() {
  return {
      events: [
        { 
          id: 1, 
          name: "Event 1",
          timeslot: {}
        },
        { 
          id: 2, 
          name: "Event 2",                  
          timeslot: {}
        }
      ],
      selectedEvents: [],
      toggleCheck: []
  }
}
```

Comment: `Vue.set(event, 'timeslot', response_item.timeslot)` fixed my issue! Thanks!